# How to unregister table from django admin whose created when package are installed

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to remove some table or section form my django admin.

for example: i install summernote package who created attachment table in my admin. i dont want to show this table in admin (see in below screenshot)

[image]

Comment: find ```admin.py``` file in summernote package and remove ```Attachment``` model from ```admin.site.register()``` function.

Comment: summernote is implemented as an *Django* app, I guess.

Comment: @gachdavit I feel so bad about your solution since it's not a proper way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unregister default models in `admin.py` of your app by using `unregister`.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_summernote.models import Attachment

admin.site.unregister(Attachment)
```

Comment: when i put your code i got error like:  admin.site.unregister(Attachment)
NameError: name 'Attachment' is not defined

Comment: You need to import *Attachment* from *summernote* to works. I've edit my answer to do so.

Comment: i have also one question for summernote. I add sumuuernote in django admin model   when i fetch this content form database its display like html : <ul><li>hello user<i>how are you</i>

Comment: I didn't get your question. Could you explain more?

Comment: i use summernote for description field in product form in django admin. now i fetch this product description in frontend product details page but i got  with html not only contain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194478/discussion-between-binjal-patel-and-mrzrm).

Comment: You can use ‍‍`|safe` to get contents only.

Answer (score 6):

In your `settings.py`, change the **`INSTALLED_APPS`** structure something as below,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_summernote',  # this is the third-party app
    'my_django_app',  # this is your app
    ...
]
```

Then, in the **`admin.py`** of **`my_django_app`**

```
from django_summernote.models import Attachment
admin.site.unregister(Attachment)
```

---

The ***order of `INSTALLED_APPS`*** structure is important here. Because, Django loads each apps according to the order in which we put those in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.